# Floating Header, is there a better method than mine?

Tags: html, css

So heres [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TB2Lv/)

Below is the code, and this is primarily how I've always made a floating header.  I just wanted to know if there is a better way to do it, or a new expectation on how to do them.

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    Header
</div>
<div id="page">
    Content is to be Displayed Here
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #6cc3eb;
    z-index: 990;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#page {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    background: #ddf2fc;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, to make it easier to deal with collapsing margins at the top of the content area, I add `overflow: auto` to the containing block:

```
#page {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    background: #ddf2fc;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This forces `#page` to start a block-formatting context which means that any top margin for the first child element of `#page` will be positioned 50px from the top of the page.  Depending on your design, this can be advantageous.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

See example with `h1` at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/uvRXZ/

Comment: Yeah, overflow would have been added either way, mainly do to having navigation and logo's in the header.  Nice information to know though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only change I'd make is to use the HTML5 tag

```
<header>
```

instead of

```
<div id="header">
```

Comment: How do you know that he/she is using html5?

Comment: Not to be rude, but I am not using HTML5 today, and I do understand that it's 2013.  I haven't moved in to HTML5 as of yet, because a lot of people still don't use HTML5, yet use my coding.  I have a general understanding of HTML5 and can code in it, but not everyone can.

Comment: Pretty much everyone is using HTML5 tags ( http://caniuse.com/html5semantic ), it's only IE8 and earlier that doesn't do it, and that's easily resolved with the HTML5shiv.